# Caffeine cache yaml config expireAfterWrite not clearing the cache

Tags: spring-boot, caffeine-cache

This is my configuration
In application.yaml

```yaml
spring:
  cache:
    cache-names: portalInfo
    caffeine:
      spec: maximumSize=500, expireAfterWrite=30s
```

And In my repository

I have

```
@Cachable(key="'key1'",sync=true)
List<Employee> getAllEmployee(){}
```

So I am expecting my cache will be cleared after 30s but it's not clearing the cache

Comment: How are you detecting it is not clearing the cache?

Comment: I am calling the API which is calling this method , for first time it's calling database but next time it's getting values from cache, even after waiting for say 2-3 min DB call is not happening

Comment: You haven't specified the cache name to use in `@Cacheable`, also did you include caffeine as the cache implementation or only the configuration, if you didn't the config isn't doing much.